# How can we show that the adjacency matrix of a regular graph commutes with its complement

Tags: graph-theory

> How can we show that the adjacency matrix of a regular graph commutes with its complement?

I have read on StackExchange that the adjacency matrix of a regular graph commutes with the adjacency matrix of their own complement, but haven't been able to find any papers with a solid proof.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of an adjacency matrix: $a_{ij}=1$ iff $i$ and $j$ are connected by an arc ? And what about diagonal elements $a_{ii}$ ? $=0$?, and even more important, which matrix do you call its complement ?

Comment: Let us also bear in mind the assumption of a *regular graph* (that all vertices have equal degrees).

Comment: What is the complement of a matrix??

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix for a graph (undirected) with all $n$ vertices of degree $d$.  Its complement is $E-A-I$ where $E$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of all $1$'s.  It suffices to show that $EA = AE$.  But 
$E = e e^T$ where $e$ is the column vector of all $1$'s, $Ae = d e$,
and $e^T A = (A e)^T = d e^T$, so $EA = AE = d E$.

Comment: Why is $Ae=de$? Ah because $i^{th}$ row of $Ae$ is the degree of vertex $i$.